# fabric js stroke with gradient

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

With fabric js, I have draw a circle and want to reproduce this stroke gradient

```
 grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0,0,radius*0.95, 0,0,radius*1.05);
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
  grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
```

actually I got

```
 circle_in.setGradient("stroke", {
  type:"radial", 
  x1 : 0,
  y1 : 0,
  x2 : 0,
  y2 : 0,
  r1 :  this._clock_radius*0.95,
  r2 : this._clock_radius*1.05,
  colorStops : {0 : "#333", 0.5: "#fff", 1:"#333"}
 });
```

But not working .

Any help?

Comment: have you taken a look at http://fabricjs.com/demos for any examples of what you want to do, its comprehensive